# Creating reusable views in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder, ios9

I have recently started to develop apps for the iOS platform after having a break from it. During the break I have been programming a lot of Java Swing applications and I am baffled by the fact that there are so hard to create reusable views in iOS.

Our team created small reusable GUI components for "everything". The container view that was introduced some versions ago doesn't help in all situations since you can't embed it in for instance a `UITableViewCell` if the table is dynamic.

People are writing about don't use XIB's anymore, use Storyboard (blah blah). It makes me worried when use code like this for my reusable views:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
[self addSubview: self.contentView];
```

So I wonder, what is the state of reusable views by the end of year 2015? Is this the way to do it or are there better ways now?

*(And of course I use Swift now, I am just copy-pasting from an old project)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> People are writing about don't use XIB's anymore

Ignore that. What you're doing is the way to do it. A *.xib* file is just a way of encapsulating all the code you'd need to instantiate and configure a view and its subviews, which is exactly what you want.

The only thing I would do differently is to use UINib rather than NSBundle, because when you load using UINib you get caching, which saves time if you're going to load this nib multiple times.

(Of course, you *could* do it with a storyboard too. But that's overkill, because the contents of a storyboard always involve a UIViewController, and you don't need one in this situation.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Hearing it from you makes me confident that I am not on the wrong track!

Comment: And what you say about that I could do it with storyboards; you mean that I write each UI component in a separate storyboard?

Comment: A storyboard is just a collection of nibs, and a _.xib_ file is just a nib, so it's not like there's a huge difference. You can fetch any view controller out of a storyboard by its storyboard id, and it will load its view as soon as you refer to it, so that's a form of loading. But, as I say, you don't need a view controller as a carrier of _this_ view, so what you're doing is better.